How to make <C-CR> not sending 13;5u to the terminal (on Windows)?
On Windows if I hit Ctrl+Enter on a terminal emulation triggered by the :terminal command I get the 13;5u string and not the behavior of Ctrl+Enter
Context: If I run ipython in a terminal, when I type Ctrl+Enter I expect the cell to be evaluated (and not 13;5u to be inserted).

If I had the following code to my vimrc file the correct sequence is sent to the console.
tnoremap <expr> <C-Cr> SendToTerm("\<Esc>\<Cr>")

function! SendToTerm(what)
  call term_sendkeys('', a:what)
  return ''
endfunction

